# Working out the Average and LEFT JOIN tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying join the average of the `rating` column based on the `postid` with another table.

I've created this code which calculates the `rating` average and it works:

```
SELECT post_rating.postid, 
       AVG(post_rating.rating) 
FROM post_rating 
GROUP BY post_rating.postid"
```

However when I try to join it doesn't work, as below:

```
$join = ' LEFT JOIN ('SELECT post_rating.postid, 
                      AVG(post_rating.rating) 
                      FROM post_rating 
                      GROUP BY post_rating.postid') AS post_rating 
            ON post_rating.postid=theList.id';
```

How do I do join this code or is there a better way to do it? Thank you!

The entire code I am using:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', 'root', 'root');
$select = 'SELECT theList.id, theList.name, post_rating.rating, post_rating.postid';
$from = ' FROM theList';
$where = ' WHERE TRUE';
$join = ' LEFT JOIN ('SELECT post_rating.postid, AVG(post_rating.rating) FROM post_rating GROUP BY post_rating.postid') AS post_rating ON post_rating.postid=theList.id';
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');
if (in_array("pub", $opts)){
$where .= " AND pub = 1";
}
if (in_array("bar", $opts)){
$where .= " AND bar = 1";
}
if (in_array("restaurant", $opts)){
$where .= " AND restaurant = 1";
}
if (in_array("club", $opts)){
$where .= " AND club = 1";
}

$sql = $select . $from . $join . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
?>
```

Here are simplified versions of my tables:

postid Table

```
id | postid | rating
--------------------
1  |    3   |    5
2  |    3   |    4
3  |    1   |    3
```

theList Table

```
id | name 
----------
1  | name1   
2  | name2   
3  | name3
```

What I am trying to essentially output is:

```
id | name  | rating
------------------
1  | name1 |   3
2  | name2 |   0
3  | name3 |   4.5
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" -- What is the MySQL error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are approaching this query in an unnecessary complicated fashion. Simply do `Left Join` between the tables, consider `theList` as Leftmost table, and calculate [`Avg()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) in a Group by on the `postid`:

```
SELECT tl.id, 
       tl.name, 
       AVG(pr.rating) AS rating 
FROM post_rating AS pr 
LEFT JOIN theList AS tl ON tl.id = pr.postid 
GROUP BY tl.id, tl.name
```

Your PHP Code will look as follows:

```
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', 'root', 'root');
$select = 'SELECT tl.id, 
                  tl.name, 
                  AVG(pr.rating) AS rating ';

$from = ' FROM post_rating AS pr ';
$where = ' WHERE 1 = 1 ';
$join = ' LEFT JOIN theList AS tl ON tl.id = pr.postid ';
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');
if (in_array("pub", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND pub = 1";
}
if (in_array("bar", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND bar = 1";
}
if (in_array("restaurant", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND restaurant = 1";
}
if (in_array("club", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND club = 1";
}

$group = ' GROUP BY tl.id, tl.name ';

$sql = $select . $from . $join . $where . $group;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
?>
```

Comment: Really? This query is misusing MySQL's extended GROUP BY "feature".. With other words using columns in the SELECT without using them in the GROUP BY.. This is not ANSI SQL complaint and can cause unrelated data for every non aggregated select column which is not in the group by.

Comment: @RaymondNijland although corrected, but tl.id and pr.postid were functionally dependent via join

Comment: The Functional Dependency Special Cases can only work when the column used in the GROUP BY has a (PRIMARY or UNIQUE) key dependency https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html#functional-dependence-special-cases atleast that is what i have understood when reading the documentation..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for clarifying. Although, I felt that it is safe to assume that `tl.id` is a primary key in `theList` table, and since we are joining using `tl.id = pr.postid`; it should not matter whether I group by `tl.id` or `pr.postid`

Comment: " it should not matter whether I group by tl.id or pr.postid" Well the documention explains the column or columns used in `GROUP BY` are used to do the functional dependency... "Thus, co.name is **functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns and the query is valid.** " so clearly it looks like it does matter... Also the Functional Dependencies Derived from Multiple-Column Keys (JOINING) and from Equalities follows this if you look close.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have had success in using this code to get the rating. Thank You! However now the WHERE TRUE statement is not working and getting and error! Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: @tbowden why do you need Where true ?

Comment: I have some checkboxes that basically help me refine query. So the code works by checking if the checkboxes are checked, then returns the results based on which checkboxes are checked! - Can you see how it works above? Thanks!

Comment: @tbowden check the updated answer. I have added the modified PHP code also

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Now I see the issue you were trying to tell me about in your previous question comments, you have ended the `$join` string for some reason so most of the query wont be included

So this line

```
$join = ' LEFT JOIN ('SELECT post_rating.postid, AVG(post_rating.rating) 
            FROM post_rating GROUP BY post_rating.postid') AS post_rating 
            ON post_rating.postid=theList.id';
```

(see the code colour shows the error)

So amend to

```
$join = ' LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_rating.postid, AVG(post_rating.rating) 
            FROM post_rating GROUP BY post_rating.postid) AS post_rating 
            ON post_rating.postid=theList.id';
```

Can I suggest that you add EXCEPTION processing to PDO so you get told on your browser when there are errors. Do this in your connection code

```
$pdo = new PDO(.......);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Still getting a 500 error! Is there something else i'm missing? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: 500 errors are usually pretty serious. Have you looked in your PHP Error log to see if there are any messages that will help identify the issue

Comment: "Still getting a 500 error! Is there something else i'm missing?" Move to a other hosting provider that doesn't force a white screen of death on you when the PHP parser fails. @tbowden .. then you would have a more usefull error. Or do what RiggsFolly says looks into a PHP error file if you have access to it... if you don't have access to it use this in your code `ini_set('error_log', 'your/path/to/errors.log');`

Comment: I would guess you changed something other than just this! This error should have generated a fairly normal error and certainly not a 500

Comment: Learning a lot here! Thanks guys. I have figure out the error! For some reason its saying "1054 Unknown column 'post_rating.rating' in 'field list'".

Comment: The rating column in the post_rating table definitely exists!

Comment: You need an alias: `AVG(post_rating.rating) AS rating`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to say `post_rating.` before all the columns in the subquery, since there's only one table there.